# Manually change the status of a job to successful in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

For some troubleshooting, I need to manually change the status of a running job from `active` to `successful` to make it completed. The job itself is an infinite loop that does not finish. The option to delete the job cannot be used because it puts the job in a failed state.

Update: The job actually does not fail, instead it gets stuck, and therefore I delete it which makes it go to the failed state. Also, it is not possible to change the code of the job (it is not a bash script).

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you able to change the code executed by the job? If yes, what language do you use there?

Comment: Thanks. I do not know how to change the code in a running pod. The job runs a Java application.

Comment: Why do you need to make it successful? Is this part of some sort of pipeline?

Comment: Other jobs are depending on it. Making it successful allows the rest to continue, otherwise if I kill this job they will stop. This is for quick troubleshooting where I do not want to stop the rest to add a bypass for the status of this job.

Comment: I would temporary append shell command `|| exit 0` to the entry point of the Job container to force the Job to report success even if its main command fails.

Comment: Thanks @VAS. I agree. However, please note that actually the job does not fail; instead it gets struck, and therefore I delete it. This is why the job goes to the failed state. Sorry for the not complete description. I will update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you are more interested in treating the symptoms of your problem than the actual reasons behind them.

> This is for quick troubleshooting where I do not want to stop the rest
> to add a bypass for the status of this job.

I think that quicker way would be to actually make sure that your other jobs are less dependable on this one instead of trying to force Kubernetes to mark this Job/Pod as successful.

The closest thing I could get to your goal was to `curl` api-server directly with `kube-proxy`. But that solution only works if the job is failed first and unfortunately it does not work with running pods.

For this example I used job that exits with status 1:

```yaml
      containers:
        - name: job
          image: busybox
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo sleeping....; sleep 5s; exit 1;
```

Then run `kubectl-proxy`:

```java
➜  ~ kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
[1] 18372
➜  ~ Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

And post the status to api-server:

```sh
curl localhost:8080/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/default/jobs/job3/status -XPATCH  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" -d '{"status": {"succeeded": 1}}'
```

```java
    ],
    "startTime": "2021-01-28T14:02:31Z",
    "succeeded": 1,
    "failed": 1
  }
}%
```

If then check the job status I can see that it was marked as completed.

```java
➜  ~ k get jobs
NAME   COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job3   1/1           45s        45s
```

PS. I tried this way to set up the status to successful/completed for either the job or pod but that was not possible. The status changed for  moment and then `controller-manager` reverted the status to running. Perhaps this small `window` with status changed might be what you want and it will allow your other jobs to move on. I'm merely assuming this since I don't the details.

For more reading how to access API in that way please have a look at the [using kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#using-kubectl-proxy) docs.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that this would not be the best approach.